# Is it possible to fix some weights for selected neurons during training? If yes? how can I do it?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a NN with several layers, but in one of the layers, **I need to vary the weights and biases (w & b) of some neurons** and yet, allow others w & b of other neurons in the same layer to change during the training. I'm using PyTorch.

So let's say that *layer n* has **X1 + X2 = X** neurons. I need to fix w & b for **X1** neurons and let the others for **X2** neurons change during training.

A simple starter idea would do me well, on how to even go about it!

I have tried to use `LocallyConnected1D` layers but a visualization of the network depicts something very different from what I need.

Answer (score 1):

From [PyTorch example for using a trained CNN as a fixed feature extractor for a single layer perceptron](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#convnet-as-fixed-feature-extractor), doing the following :

```py
model_conv = torchvision.models.resnet18(weights='IMAGENET1K_V1')
for param in model_conv.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

freezes the parameters of `model_conv`. The example on PyTorch website then proceeds to pass the output of `model_conv` to a `Linear` layer which is trained as usual.

According to [the documentation for the `requires_grad` parameter](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/autograd.html#setting-requires-grad), this is the recommended way to freeze parts of your model :

> Setting requires_grad should be the main way you control which parts of the model are part of the gradient computation, for example, if you need to freeze parts of your pretrained model during model fine-tuning.

By adding an `if` conditional to the example above, you should be able to freeze only some of the parameters while leaving the other trainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for name, parameter in yournetwork.named_parameters():
     if 'key' in name:
         parameter.requires_grad = False
```

You can change the 'key' into the parametes you want to fix and this operation will freezes the weights of the layer you chose.